# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT for C++ Input

Tags: c++, xcode, file-io, sigabrt

I am trying to read input from a file that looks like this:

```
7
3
5
1
6
2
14
10
```

I am trying to save the first number in the integer N but I am getting and error when using stoi() and it gives me the error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT":

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion
terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion
(lldb)
```

I did some research and found that it threw the error because it couldn't convert it to an integer. How do I read input from txt files and save them in integers? I'm using Xcode as the IDE. I didn't find anything on stack overflow with this specific question. Thanks in advance! My entire code is below:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("div7.in");
    int N = -1;
    
    string str = line; // a variable of string data type
    N = std::stoi(str);
    cout << '\n N: ' << N << endl;
    
    
    while (getline (myfile, line)){
        cout << line << "\n";
    }
    myfile.close();
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MikeCAT I added my code, is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did

```
string str = line; // a variable of string data type
N = std::stoi(str);
```

without reading data from the file to `line`.

Add

```
getline (myfile, line);
```

before

```
string str = line; // a variable of string data type
```

to read a line from the file.

Adding check to see if file opening and reading are successful will make your code better.

Comment: The code now works but when I output N it outputs "5419976007" instead of "7". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @TeeSwizzle It looks like a combination of an implementation-defined value of multiple-character character constant `'\n N: '` (it looks like `541997600` in your environment) and the value of `N`, which is `7`. String literals in C++ should be surrounded by double quotes `""`, not by single quotes `''`.